# Prop.test and fisher's exact test in R

Tags: r, testing, statistics, statistical-test

I am confused about the use of fisher's exact test comparing two proportions. For example, I want to test whether there is a difference between two proportions 9/13 and 3/18. I can simply type

```
A <-  c( 9, 3)
B <-  c( 13, 18)
prop.test(A , B)
```

but how to conduct this using fisher's exact test? I am not sure if this is correct:

```
A = matrix(c(9, 3,
             13,18), nrow = 2)

fisher.test(A)
```

Thankfull for any ideas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your set-up for the Fisher's test is incorrect as compared to the `prop.test()`.

From prop.test help file:

```
prop.test(x, n, p = NULL, alternative = c("two.sided", "less", "greater"), conf.level = 0.95, correct = TRUE)

x a vector of counts of successes,...

n a vector of counts of trials ...
```

The Fisher test

```
fisher.test(x, y = NULL, workspace = 200000, hybrid = FALSE,
            hybridPars = c(expect = 5, percent = 80, Emin = 1),
            control = list(), or = 1, alternative = "two.sided",
            conf.int = TRUE, conf.level = 0.95,
            simulate.p.value = FALSE, B = 2000)

x a two-dimensional contingency table in matrix form.
```

So if your 2 tests of 13 and 18 trials resulted in 9 and 3 successes, that would mean the failures were 4 and 15, thus the Fishers test should be:

```
A = matrix(c(9, 3, 4, 15), nrow = 2)
#Row sums are the total number of trials
#Column sums are the total number of True/False
 
fisher.test(A)

    Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  A
p-value = 0.007518
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
  1.61038 89.70868
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
  10.18122
```

This provides results comparable to the prop.test results.

Comment: "a two-dimensional contingency table".  A Contingency table is a table of the counts for the successes and failures for each condition.  Wiki can provide a better definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table